# Finding $y$-intercept of a parallel line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have two parallel lines. The equation of the first line is

$$y = -x -3.$$

The distance between the parallel lines is $0.5$. How do I find the $y$-intercept of the second line?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean $$y=-x-3$$?

Comment: yes, I could of written it that way too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x+y+k=0$ be an equation of the second line.

Thus, $$\frac{|k-3|}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

The slopes of the lines are $-1$. They make $45^\circ$ with the negative $x$-axis.  If the distance between the two lines is $\frac{1}{2}$, the difference between their $y$-intercepts should be $\frac{1}{2}\div\cos45^\circ$. There are two possibilities. The second line may have a larger or a smaller $y$-intercept.